# Functional analysis: semi positive integrals

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose f,p,q are continuous function on R satisfying:

$\int f \phi dx$  $\geq$ 0

$\int p \phi' dx$  $\geq$ 0

$\int q \phi'' dx$  $\geq$ 0

What can one say about f,p,q?

$\phi \in C^\inf_0(R)$ and $\phi \geq 0$

Comment: Any assumptions on $\phi$? And can you say something about where the problem is coming from?

Comment: yeah just added, sorry forgot that peice. Its just a homework problem from my functional analysis course.

Comment: If this is to be for only a single $\phi$, there is probably not much to be said. It doesn't make much sense to ask it for all $\phi$. Are you perhaps assuming the inequalities hold for all $\phi\ge0$? And can you say something about where the problem is coming from, and what your own thoughts on it are?

Comment: Ah yes $\phi$ is non negative

Comment: Well, $f$ is the easy one. Can you see why $f\ge0$? (Hint: select $\phi$ with support in a small neighbourhood around some point where $f$ is negative to get a contradiction.) If $p$ is differentiable and $q$ is twice differentiable, do some partial integrations to get the derivatives off $\phi$. This should at least tell you what the answers *ought* to be.

Comment: Ah i see, unfortunately we are not given that f,p,q are differentiable. So perhaps we can't say anything about p and q.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is negative somewhere, because of continuity, it is negative in a neighborhood $U$, then take a $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\mathrm{supp}(\varphi) \subseteq U$ and $\varphi \geq 0$. Then $f\varphi \leq 0$, so $\int f\varphi \leq 0$, which means (due to hypothesis) $\int f \varphi = 0$, so $f \varphi = 0$, meaning $f$ is $0$ on $U$, absurd. This means that $f$ is positive, as it can't be negative nowhere.

Think about the other ones in a similar fashion.

Comment: for the other ones having $\phi \geq 0 $ does not imply that  $\phi' \geq 0 $ right?

Comment: No, of course not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $p$ is differentiable, a partial integration leads to $\int p'\phi\,dx\le0$. From the $f$ case (for which, see sjvega's answer), conclude that $p'\le0$; i.e., that $p$ is decreasing (non-increasing if you prefer). So it seems reasonable to conjecture that $p$ must be decreasing even if it is not differentiable.

Similarly, if $q$ is twice differentiable, you can do two partial integrations and get … that $q$ is convex. Again, conjecture that this is true even without any differentiability assumptions on $q$.

To prove the first of these conjectures, assume $a<b$ and try to prove that $p(a)\le p(b)$. I suggest trying a function $\phi$ which is zero, then increases to $1$ within a small neighbourhood around $a$, then remains constant until it drops back down to $0$in a s small neighbourhood of $b$.